# Regex to search class and id names in HTML files

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm creating a script that takes in a user inputted class/id name and then it parses through all of my HTML files and locates+prints any lines that include them.

The closest I've gotten is: `class=["']((.*?)(USER_INPUT_NAME))[\s"']`

- I'm going to be utilizing this in Python so I understand I will have to include escape characters to allow it to perform properly.

This still poses issues for lines like:

- `<div class="cover-container">` when only searching for 'container' -- I end up with it locating 'cover-container'
- `<button type="button" class="close modal-exit" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">` when only searching for 'modal' it clearly exceeds the bounds of class and finds it in another identifier.

I'm clearly not the best with regex and I've been trying to solve it by utilizing other questions but I can't seem to get there because the '-' throw my regex off and staying within the class="" quotes is throwing it off. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you consider using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse your html??

Comment: @wwii I initially thought of that too but how would it return the line number and content of that line?

Comment: Hard to say as your [mre] does not include in example data and it isn't clear (to me at least) what exactly you are trying to do. Parsing html you cannot expect there to be any *lines* - you can't expect that the html string *was pretty-printed* so line numbers don't usually mean anything; once you find a tag you can usually find siblings, parents, neighbors..., and their content.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```perl
[ \"'](?:class|id)=(\")(?:(?!\1).+ | *)container(?: (?!\1).+| *)\1
```

https://regex101.com/r/0Zu0ze/1

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! So this works for the container class name, but when I try other class names it doesn't seem to work. Nonetheless, you use some cool features of regex that I wasn't completely aware of how to use, so I'm going to use your example and try redesigning. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanFromOhio I'm glad you like it. If you feel that it solves your issue then feel free to mark it as accepted; it took me quite some time to get it right. If you can, provide a regex101 link with failing regex/data and I might be able to point you in the right direction.